# Is it possible to create a Safe on Base mainnet with the same address as an existing safe on Eth mainnet?

Tags: gnosis-safe

Need to deploy a Safe on Base mainnet that has the same address as an existing Safe on Eth mainnet.

Following the [instructions provided by this Loom video](https://www.loom.com/share/ca34aabcd62747fb9fb89bd463b4c741) and am clear on all the steps, but there's one part that I want to get explicitly clear on because it gets glossed over in the video...

...is it not possible to do this because of the fact that the Ethereum GnosisSafeProxyFactory 1.3.0 address is `0xa6B71E26C5e0845f74c812102Ca7114b6a896AB2` and the Base  GnosisSafeProxyFactory 1.3.0 address is `0xC22834581EbC8527d974F8a1c97E1bEA4EF910BC`?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the contract implementation (https://etherscan.io/address/0xa6B71E26C5e0845f74c812102Ca7114b6a896AB2#code), the address was generated through CREATE opcode, would be `keccak256(rlp([address(this), this.nonce]))` https://github.com/wolflo/evm-opcodes/blob/main/gas.md#a9-create-operations.

Since they don't have the same address, it's might not possible to have the same address.